# Absolute pass on RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want users access the cgi script for searching tags in my blog, but the script is in another directory.  Is it possible to let RewriteRule to access to another directory?  I tried my own method but its not working so far.

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]*)/$ /var/www/html/script/search.cgi?tag=$1 [L]
```

When a user access `blog.com/tag/apple/` search.cgi searches for tag "apple"

My blog's aboslute pass is

> /var/www/html/blog/

Search script is here

> /var/www/html/script/search.cgi

Comment: Is your server properly configured to serve that CGI script?

Comment: yes when I enter http://cms.testsite.com/script/search.cgi?tag=apple (my cms address) expected results shows up.

Comment: Alright. Be more specific about "not working" then.

Comment: `search.cgi` has to be inside `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# forwards to script/search.cgi?tag=foo if URI is tag/foo
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]*)/?$ script/search.cgi?tag=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Make sure you add this code to your .htaccess file in `/var/www/html` directory.